# .asmx file with missing source file does not throw compile error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an AspNet web application. It has a .asmx web service. The contents follow:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/SystemNotificationsService.cs" Class="SystemNotificationsService2" %>
```

Note that the codebehind does not exist. The class does not exist. Yet it still compiles without error. Does it not process this file until runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: That line is more like a reference, not actual code, so it doesn't really compile in the same sense. I've never really confirmed it, but I think that's more or less right. P.S. If there's no code, the asmx file could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that everything in `App_Code` does not compile until it is accessed. Is this an old style website app and not a webapp? If it is a webapp you should not use the `App_Code` folder - especially if you are using newer version of C# as you'll get errors.

Comment: It was a website app. I copy/pasted all the files into the website app into the new project. At first it wouldn't run because of the app_code. It was causing duplicate references until I renamed the App_Code folder to AppCode. In this particular .asmx file I forgot to update the codebehind to point it to the new location and was surprised to find it still compiled. Even when I entered a non-existent class in the .asmx file it still compiled. My conclusion is that it doesn't even look at this file until runtime.

Comment: New project? The new project is a webapp or a website - a new project should not have a App_Code folder. I don't understand where you say "In this particular .asmx file I forgot to update the codebehind to point it to the new location". To test just put the C# in the .asmx file.

I would create a new WebApp project and try again.

Comment: Original project was a WebSite project, I created a new webapp project. And copied contents of old project into new project. Thus, it had an App_Code folder, but webApp projects shouldn't have a folder named App_Code, so I renamed it to AppCode. I updated all codebehind refences that pointed to renamed folder. Everything works. I was just suprised to find that it completely ignores the asmx file at compile time. It appears it waits until runtime, then looks at the class name.